# Having trouble passing the user's text entry value to the search aspect of the selenium script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, return-value

I'm trying to get an address from the user and pass it to the selenium portion of the program to be searched but I'm only able to get the default value of var textentry. This seems way too simple but I've been stuck on it for hours. Please help! My click function correctly can get the user input but I'm not able to access it globally. How can this be done. Thank you in advance!!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog   #input input()
from tkinter import messagebox   #output print()
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains as AC 
import time

#:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::GUI

def close_win():
    window.destroy()

def click():
    entered_text = textentry.get()
    # print(entered_text)
    close_win()
    return entered_text
    


window = Tk()
window.title('Camson Crown (Uni. Hillsborough)')
window.configure(background="light grey")
window.geometry("400x300")

#   create text entry box:
textentry = Entry(window, width=25, bg="white", borderwidth=5)   #textVariable=enteredAddress, Default val = .!entry
textentry.place(x=120, y=120)
entered_text = textentry     #default val is .!entry
placeholder = "Example: 1015 Mexicala"
textentry.insert(0, placeholder)
print(entered_text)

#create text box label:
entry_box_label = Label(window, text="Address here")
entry_box_label.place(x=162, y=95)

#   add a submit button:
submit_button = Button(window, text="SUBMIT", width=7, command=click)
submit_button.place(x=168, y=148)

window.mainloop() # root.mainloop will need to be at the end of the gui setup 

#Create a Label widget to display the text or Image  # NOT WORKING > unknown error.
# label = tk.Label(window, image = img)
# label.pack(fill = "both", expand= "yes")

# button = Button(window, text="popup", command=get_address)
# button.pack()  #initiates
# get_address()

#:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::     Selenium Start

propertyAddress = entered_text   #NOT WORKING > unknown error. #"1015 Mexicala"     # INSERT PROPERTY ADDRESS BETWEEN QUOTES. Example: ("1015 Mexicala")



PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()

Selenium script continues to search the address from he input and works correctly.
```

Comment: instead of `return entered_text` asign the value to a variable (which You have done already) and asign it globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the option with using classes (more like one class which also sort of helps with organizing the code):

```
from tkinter import *


class EntryWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title('Camson Crown (Uni. Hillsborough)')
        self.window.configure(background="light grey")
        self.window.geometry("400x300")

        #   create text entry box:
        self.textentry = Entry(self.window, width=25, bg="white", borderwidth=5)   #textVariable=enteredAddress, Default val = .!entry
        self.textentry.place(x=120, y=120)
        self.placeholder = "Example: 1015 Mexicala"
        self.textentry.insert(0, self.placeholder)
        self.property_address = ''

        #create text box label:
        self.entry_box_label = Label(self.window, text="Address here")
        self.entry_box_label.place(x=162, y=95)

        #   add a submit button:
        self.submit_button = Button(self.window, text="SUBMIT", width=7, command=self.submit)
        self.submit_button.place(x=168, y=148)

        self.window.mainloop()

    def submit(self):
        self.property_address = self.textentry.get()
        self.window.destroy()


main_window = EntryWindow()
print(main_window.property_address)
```

and as it can be seen it does not really differ from the variant without using classes. only thing is pretty much just adding `self.`. this just allows to access all the variables in the class which is handy

this should also fix the issue:

```
from tkinter import *


def close_win():
    window.destroy()


def click():
    global entered_text
    entered_text = textentry.get()
    close_win()


window = Tk()
window.title('Camson Crown (Uni. Hillsborough)')
window.configure(background="light grey")
window.geometry("400x300")

#   create text entry box:
textentry = Entry(window, width=25, bg="white", borderwidth=5)   #textVariable=enteredAddress, Default val = .!entry
textentry.place(x=120, y=120)
entered_text = textentry     #default val is .!entry
placeholder = "Example: 1015 Mexicala"
textentry.insert(0, placeholder)
print(entered_text)

#create text box label:
entry_box_label = Label(window, text="Address here")
entry_box_label.place(x=162, y=95)

#   add a submit button:
submit_button = Button(window, text="SUBMIT", width=7, command=click)
submit_button.place(x=168, y=148)

window.mainloop()

propertyAddress = entered_text

print(propertyAddress)
```

as You can see I made entered text global and that is it, in this case there is no point of `return` since it returns it nowhere. now it should work.

in case You wonder where are changes (in the second example):

```
def click():
    global entered_text
    entered_text = textentry.get()
    close_win()
```

Comment: I have been working to not use the global keyword as I'm told it's a "no no". However I can't figure out why the return isn't giving me the value of the variable for the user input. I don't believe I should have to use the global keyword as that is what the return statement is for, correct? Thank you for your comment! This code does work as long as I run it with the VS code editor. As soon as I try to create an .exe or run the .py file it self terminates. All of my other programs (which don't have the tkinter GUI and global declaration) run without any issues.

Comment: @CoreyGrandmaison ok, then the only idea that comes to mind (for me at least) is to use classes (will give You an example in a moment) and yes I also have heard that global variables are not that good (sth about debugging and other stuff)

Comment: @Matiss, I'm grateful. /\
I'll make sure to check back for your update. I have tried to mark your answer as helpful but my rep is below 15 so it doesn't count. :/
 I made sure to select your answer as accepted. I have never used classes yet so I'm looking forward to learning from your reply. Once again Thank you!

Comment: @CoreyGrandmaison I don't know if You get a notification if an edit has been made but I added the code which uses classes: actually [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM&list=PL-osiE80TeTsqhIuOqKhwlXsIBIdSeYtc) is a series of tutorials about classes if You are interested (at least I recommend). (and did You receive the notification about the edit? just curios) and obviously if You have any issues just ask

Comment: I did get a notification in my "inbox" actually! I'm going to dive into this right now. It's been way too long and too much resistance against classes. It's time for me to get on the Classes train.  I'll let you know if I have any trouble using __init__. I'm following you now @Matiiss, you've been sterling in your response and a great teacher. Humbly, Thank you /\

Comment: @CoreyGrandmaison that was rather flattering, thank You! (Your response actually made me happier)